# Unable to connect to Ryuk?

Tags: testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

Hi I am trying to spin up a test container from my unit test class.

from my test class i am using the following

```
   @Container
    private static GenericContainer<?> testContainer =  new GenericContainer<>(TEST_IMAGE)
            .withCommand("sleep infinity")
//            .withLogConsumer(LOG_CONSUMER)
            .withNetwork(dockerNetwork).withNetworkAliases(TESTCONTAINER_NETWORK_ALIAS);
```

however when i run my test i get the error below

```
SEVERE: Caught exception while closing extension context: org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassExtensionContext@495ee280
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not connect to Ryuk at 172.17.0.1:4750
        at org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper.start(ResourceReaper.java:227)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:219)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory$1.getDockerClient(DockerClientFactory.java:101)
        at com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClientDelegate.authConfig(DockerClientDelegate.java:107)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:316)
        at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.start(TestcontainersExtension.java:242)
        at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.access$200(TestcontainersExtension.java:229)
        at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$null$1(TestcontainersExtension.java:59)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$0(ExtensionValuesStore.java:81)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:182)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:84)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:53)
        at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$beforeAll$2(TestcontainersExtension.java:59)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
        at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.beforeAll(TestcontainersExtension.java:59)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:359)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:359)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:189)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:132)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
```

appreciate any help
thanks

Comment: Can you share some more information about your environment? Which OS, how is Docker installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not connect to Ryuk at
```

This could due be low disk space as managed by the (virtual machine) environment that docker runs in. If so, you need to clean up and reclaim some space.

Reclaim disk space:

```
 docker system prune
```

If running on Windows you will probably need to reboot.

I use wsl and can confirm that *wsl --shutdown* was not sufficient, a reboot was required.